# How do I git pull -f

Tags: git

Where is

```
git pull --force
```

as in `rm -rf` and then `git clone` again from scratch?

End result should be `git diff` returns nothing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, I would also add a `git clean -fdx` to remove all untracked files and directories, to avoid potential issues with files being added in the remote repository, but also present in the current clone.

```
git clean -fdx
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 4):

You use `git fetch` to fetch everything from the remote repository. Then you can just `git reset --hard origin/master` to reset your current branch to origin’s master and reset your working directory.

Answer (score 3):

Reset your working directory back to the latest pull:

```
git reset --hard
```

Then pull as usual